# Concatenate multiple IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, concatenation, ienumerable

I'm trying to implement a method to concatenate multiple `List`s e.g.

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
List<string> l3 = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
var result = Concatenate(l1, l2, l3);
```

but my method doesn't work:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concatenate<T>(params IEnumerable<T> List)
{
    var temp = List.First();
    for (int i = 1; i < List.Count(); i++)
    {
        temp = Enumerable.Concat(temp, List.ElementAt(i));
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Calling IEnumerable.Count() every cycle is a bit of a waste. Call it once and store it in a variable, or better, use a foreach loop: `var Temp = List.First(); foreach (IEnumerable<T> sequence in List.Skip(1)) Temp = Enumerable.Concat(sequence);`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `SelectMany`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concatenate<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    return lists.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just for completeness another imo noteworthy approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concatenate<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] List)
{
    foreach (IEnumerable<T> element in List)
    {
        foreach (T subelement in element)
        {
            yield return subelement;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make your function work you need an array of IEnumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concartenate<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] List)
{
    var Temp = List.First();
    for (int i = 1; i < List.Count(); i++)
    {
        Temp = Enumerable.Concat(Temp, List.ElementAt(i));
    }
    return Temp;
}
```

Comment: The parameter `List` is an array of IEnumerables and it could contain no items. This will cause `List.First()` to throw an exception. You should first check the length of this array. I will also use the `Length` property and the indexer `List[]` instead of the equivalent Linq extensions in the for loop.

Comment: Don't use a common class name as a variable name. =(

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is to change:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concatenate<T>(params IEnumerable<T> lists)
```

to

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concatenate<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
```

Note the extra `[]`.